# C'est chaud = It's crazy ?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques, argot

I have heard the following dialogue in the TV series Unité 42:

- J'arrive pas y croire. Bob...
- C'est chaud.

Context: A team of murder investigators are talking about Bob, his fellow investigator who was recently charged with drug manufacturing and was arrested.

"chaud" doesn't make any sense as "hot" in this context, so I assume it is slang. The English subtitles say "It's crazy", but I can't find this meaning in https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/chaud/14942. Is that a usual meaning of "chaud" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can indeed find this usage in colloquial French, especially among young people. It is a fairly recent usage, so I bet Larousse has not taken it in yet.

Depending on the context, the meaning can be "that's tough" (I guess that is the meaning in your example) or "that's difficult".

Comment: I wouldn't characterize it as specific to young people. I'm pretty sure it was already common in the late 20th century.

Comment: Then let's say "among the young at heart"... I cannot picture myself above 50 someone using this spontaneously, or they could be rated as "un vieux qui essaie de parler le djeun's".

Comment: "that's messed up" would also work here

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' I concur. The expression has been recorded at least in 1992 (Cœur de banlieue: Codes, rites, et langages, David Lepoutre). I might be wrong but I believe I was already using it before that date.

Comment: Mais qu'est-ce que ça voudrait dire ici _that's tough_ ? Comme je ne connais pas l'emploi je ne sais toujours pas de quoi il en retourne dans l'exemple de la question.

Comment: Cela veut dire alors "c'est rude !" ou "c'est un sacré choc !".

Answer (score 4):

"C'est chaud" can be used in a couple similar ways in slang. For a more detailed explanation, see [Johan Tekfak from Français Authentique's explanation](https://www.francaisauthentique.com/3-expressions-a-connaitre-absolument-en-francais-2/).

1. If a situation is difficult, you could say "c'est chaud." Example: "Y'a tellement de gens dans ce bus, c'est chaud pour trouver une place."
2. Describing a tense, dangerous or chaotic situation. Example: "Les mecs sont en train de se taper dessus à coup de barre de fer, c'est chaud!"
3. If you're shocked and want to express how upsetting something is, you could also use it. Example: "Martine a eu un accident de voiture hier? Ah ouais c'est chaud quand même!"

Comment: I would add the slightly different meaning, to describe a tense, dangerous or chaotic situation. Ex: *les mecs sont en train de se taper dessus à coup de barre de fer, c'est chaud!*.

Comment: Great suggestion, XouDo! Edited to reflect the additional meaning.

Comment: Donc ici ce serait le troisième cas ?